# Building a playlist to control playback options for each media file individually in VLC/Lua

Tags: lua, vlc

I have a playlist containing video files. For each playlist item I want to control the playlist mode for whether each track should "repeat", "play-and-stop" etc. in VLC using a Lua script.

```
file:///data/video1.mp4,repeat
file:///data/video2.mp4,play-and-stop
```

The aim is that some video tracks should repeat indefinitely until the user manually advances to the next track. Other tracks in the playlist should play once and then advance to the next track, or `play-and-stop` and wait for the user to interact before play commences again.

I currently have the following code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723026/1895018), however I'm unable to apply the [playlist options](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#Playlist_options) to each track individually (the options apply to the whole playlist).  Is there any way I can extend my script to achieve this?

```
function probe()
    return string.match(vlc.path, "%.myplaylist$")
end

function parse()
    playlist = {}

    while true do
        playlist_item = {}
        line = vlc.readline()
        if line == nil then
            break

        -- parse playlist line into two tokens splitting on comma
        values = {}
        i=0
        for word in string.gmatch(line, '([^,]+)') do
            values[i]=word
            i=i+1
        end

        playlist_item.path = values[0]
        playback_mode = values[1]

        playlist_item.options = {}
        table.insert(playlist_item.options, "fullscreen")
        table.insert(playlist_item.options, playback_mode)

        -- add the item to the playlist
        table.insert( playlist, playlist_item )
    end

    return playlist
end
```

Adding ["video options"](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#Video_options) to `playlist_item.options` is working, but adding ["playlist options"](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#Playlist_options) on a per track basis does not. I'm unsure how to proceed as I can only return an entire playlist.

Comment: That sounds expected behavior to me, the playlist options would apply to the entire playlist. In your example, if the first track is on repeat, then you'll never reach any other tracks in the playlist. This is how most applications work, e.g. in Itunes/Android music apps you can select the playlist mode to be shuffle, repeat loop, repeat one or play once. Are you thinking of doing: `repeat track1 n-times` and then move on to the next item?

Comment: The aim is that some video tracks should repeat *indefinitely* until the user manually advances to the next track. Other tracks in the playlist should play once and then advance to the next track.  It's looking like I won't be able to do this as a playlist and that I'll have to manually script the entire step-by-step behavior I need VLC to perform from startup onwards (playing one file at a time whilst controlling the playlist mode)?

Comment: +1. Interesting, I don't have time to experiment on this right now, but you could look into nested playlists if that works. Some examples [here](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2007-November/036382.html), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/850163/multiple-playlists-on-vlc). Also, you should update the question to better indicate what you want.

Comment: Thank you @vsnyc for the links, I'd missed the idea of nested playlists. I've updated the question description as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a custom playlist

```
file:///data/video1.mp4,repeat
file:///data/video2.mp4,play-once
```

I completed the playlist script in the original question above by adding the repeat/play-once information to the track metadata.

```
playlist_item.meta = { ["Playback mode"] = playback_mode }
```

The final step was to create an extension (similar to the [Song Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154018/) extension) that listens to the `input_changed` event and uses the "Playback mode" track metadata to toggle `vlc.playlist.repeat_()` accordingly.

```
function activate()
  update_playback_mode()
end

function input_changed()
  update_playback_mode()
end

function update_playback_mode()
  if vlc.input.is_playing() then
    local item = vlc.item or vlc.input.item()
    if item then
      local meta = item:metas()
      if meta then
        local repeat_track = meta["Playback mode"]
        if repeat_track == nil then
          repeat_track = false
        elseif string.lower(repeat_track) == "repeat" then
          repeat_track = true
        else
          repeat_track = false
        end

    local player_mode = vlc.playlist.repeat_()

    -- toggle playlist.repeat_() as required        
    if player_mode and not repeat_track then
        vlc.playlist.repeat_()
    elseif not player_mode and repeat_track then
        vlc.playlist.repeat_()
    end

    return true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested you can solve the repeat problem by creating a playlist in VLC and saving it as a XSPF file. Then you need to edit the file with notepad and add this inside the extension tag of the track you want to repeat:

```
<vlc:option>input-repeat=9999</vlc:option>
```

Example:

```
<track>
    <location>file:///C:/Users/Notebook/Desktop/17-LOOP.mp4</location>
    <duration>10048</duration>
    <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
        <vlc:option>input-repeat=9999</vlc:option>
    </extension>
</track>
```

By doing this the moment this file is played in the playlist will repeat 9999  times(You can change this if the file is too short) or until you press next. Then the playlist will continue.

Comment: That'a a much simplier solution than I ended up writing. Thank you, I will use this next time.